# Ideal format for tag descriptions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

What is the ideal format for a tag description wiki?

For example, should the short description read "questions about X" or simply "X"?

---

(The levels of description around here can get very confusing, at least for me. I'm not sure what the intended use of [meta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) is here on [meta], but I used it in reference to my question, which concerns my confusion over descriptions and description of levels of description of tags, which is the other tag I think is relevant. Even regarding the 'tags' in the previous sentence, is not clear to me whether it should be in the object language or not.)

Comment: The [meta](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) tag, in [meta], to my mind, is for questions about [meta] (meta-meta questions, if you will). On [main], on the other hand, I'd say that [tag:meta] refers to questions about [main].

Comment: It'd probably be worthwhile to look at larger peer sites and see how they phrase their tag wikis. I'd say that the bottom lines is that each wiki should be designed to be as useful to site visitors as possible.